# primefaces inputText desn't work with ajax event

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

i used ajax `<f:ajax>` with primefaces inputText to fire specific action onBlur event but it doesn't, i tried also `<p:ajax>` but it deosn't work too!

```
<p:inputText id="Name" value="#{personBean.missingName}"
            label="Name" required="true" size="30"
            validatorMessage="Name is required" >
           <f:ajax event="blur" listener="#{personBean.validateName}"/>
</p:inputText>
```

action method inside personBean:

```
public void validateName(){
    System.err.println("OnBlur Action");
}
```

when the focus is lost from the inputText the `inputText` doesn't printed to the console

Comment: Add more context to your code. Post the surrounding form and other components. A validation/conversion error or non-submittal of the surrounding form are the only things that will cause your method to not execute

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `f:ajax` with PrimeFaces components. Also your method is not defined correclty.

```
<p:inputText id="Name" value="#{personBean.missingName}"
        label="Name" required="true" size="30"
        validatorMessage="Name is required" >
       <p:ajax event="blur" listener="#{personBean.validateName}"/>
</p:inputText>
```

Corrected method :

```
public void validateName(AjaxBehaviorEvent event){
    System.err.println("OnBlur Action");
}
```

Note that you should use

Comment: @JavaPlayer I've just tested it and it works, event using `f:ajax`. You probably have something else that prevent the action fireing. You could try with `process="@this"`.

Comment: @Alexandre Lavoie - PrimeFaces doesn't enforce you to have the AjaxBehaviourEvent - http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajaxifyAction.jsf  - process="@this" is implicit and not required as it does that anyway.

Comment: @VeenarM, I was talking about `f:ajax`, also the parameter is not necessary only if declared like `listener="#{personBean.validateName()}"` ortherwise it is necessary.

Comment: @Alexandre Lavoie - Sorry, didn't realise because you jumped from talking about f:ajax to a process= which is related to p:ajax. :) The examples on primefaces don't declare the method with the (), and i've used it with out and it works fine - (the ajax behaviour eventt (I'm talking primefaces not standard jsf)  -+1 original though